# MediaElement.js with Flash, enterFullscreen not working

Tags: mediaelement.js

I'm using MediaElement.js, and I'd like the video to start playing in fullscreen mode automatically.  This works fine when dealing with native players, I can call

```
player.enterFullscreen()
```

and it does just what I want.

But, when using the Flash Player, calling that same method, the player does not enter fullscreen, and instead shows the 'Go Fullscreen' button in the player.  (which, the user can then click and go fullscreen, but that isn't the point).

I have also tried

```
player.pluginApi.enterFullscreen()
```

but that just throws an error (no definition on that, it just says 'Error')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Flash restriction; Flash's full screen mode cannot be activated via a JavaScript event, as a security precaution against UI spoofing.

http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flashplayer/articles/full_screen_mode.html